# Absurd solution by LinearSolve

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation, signal-processing

I am trying to find curve that passes through all the data points.To do this i am doing interpolation using LinearSolve. No. of equations vary from 1000 to 3000.
LinearSolve gives me values of coefficient which I assume should be correct but when I plot the curve it does pass through those data points.
So I am not sure what Linear Solve is doing.Can anyone help me in this?
The red dots are the data points.The black curve is the curve that i got by using LinearSolve
[image]

Zt,q2,Z2t,P can be downloaded from here
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_qY4KQHuOzgSnhYZFd6RGFqdVU&usp=sharing

Here's the code

```
ClearSystemCache[]
ClearAll["Global`*"]

SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Zt = ReadList["Zt.txt"][[1]];
q2 = ReadList["q2.txt"][[1]];
Z2t = ReadList["Z2t.txt"][[1]];
P = ReadList["P.txt"][[1]];
w1 = 13;
w2 = Pi;
nP = 1.0;

(*Value of 'g' varies from 1 to 28*)

g = 12;
p2 = g;
p1 = -p2;
(*freq=frequencies present in the signal*)
freq = Sort[
   Drop[Flatten[
     N[Table[m*w1 + n*w2, {m, 0, p2}, {n, p1, p2}]]], {Abs[p2] + 1, 
     Abs[p2] + 1}]];

(*loop deletes the duplicate frequecny*)
x = Length[freq];
For[i = 1, i <= x, i++,
 For[k = 1, k <= x, k++,
  If[Abs[freq[[i]]] == freq[[k]] && i != k,
   freq = Delete[freq, k];
   x = Length[freq];
   (*i=i-1*)
   ]
  ]
 ]

(*assumed function for Zt*)
zt11 = a11[0] + 
   Sum[v11[i]*Cos[freq[[i]] t] + p11[i]*Sin[freq[[i]] t], {i, 1, 
     Length[freq]}];
zt12 = a12[0] + 
   Sum[v12[i]*Cos[freq[[i]] t] + p12[i]*Sin[freq[[i]] t], {i, 1, 
     Length[freq]}];
zt21 = a21[0] + 
   Sum[v21[i]*Cos[freq[[i]] t] + p21[i]*Sin[freq[[i]] t], {i, 1, 
     Length[freq]}];
zt22 = a22[0] + 
   Sum[v22[i]*Cos[freq[[i]] t] + p22[i]*Sin[freq[[i]] t], {i, 1, 
     Length[freq]}];

int = Length[freq]

data11 = Join[Table[Zt[[1, 1]], {y, 0, nP, nP/int}], 
   Drop[Table[Z2t[[1, 1]], {y, 0, nP, nP/int}], 1]];
data12 = Join[Table[Zt[[1, 2]], {y, 0, nP, nP/int}], 
   Drop[Table[Z2t[[1, 2]], {y, 0, nP, nP/int}], 1]];
data21 = Join[Table[Zt[[2, 1]], {y, 0, nP, nP/int}], 
   Drop[Table[Z2t[[2, 1]], {y, 0, nP, nP/int}], 1]];
data22 = Join[Table[Zt[[2, 2]], {y, 0, nP, nP/int}], 
   Drop[Table[Z2t[[2, 2]], {y, 0, nP, nP/int}], 1]];

datazt11 = Table[zt11, {t, 0, 2 nP, nP/int}];
datazt12 = Table[zt12, {t, 0, 2 nP, nP/int}];
datazt21 = Table[zt21, {t, 0, 2 nP, nP/int}];
datazt22 = Table[zt22, {t, 0, 2 nP, nP/int}];

eq11 = datazt11 - data11;
eq12 = datazt12 - data12;
eq21 = datazt21 - data21;
eq22 = datazt22 - data22;

{b11, m11} = CoefficientArrays[eq11 == 0, Variables[eq11]];
{b12, m12} = CoefficientArrays[eq12 == 0, Variables[eq12]];
{b21, m21} = CoefficientArrays[eq21 == 0, Variables[eq21]];
{b22, m22} = CoefficientArrays[eq22 == 0, Variables[eq22]];

coeff11 = LinearSolve[m11, -b11];
coeff12 = LinearSolve[m12, -b12];
coeff21 = LinearSolve[m21, -b21];
coeff22 = LinearSolve[m22, -b22];

coefv11 = Solve[Variables[eq11] - coeff11 == 0, Variables[eq11]];
coefv12 = Solve[Variables[eq12] - coeff12 == 0, Variables[eq12]];
coefv21 = Solve[Variables[eq21] - coeff21 == 0, Variables[eq21]];
coefv22 = Solve[Variables[eq22] - coeff22 == 0, Variables[eq22]];

zz = {Flatten[{zt11 /. coefv11, zt12 /. coefv12}], 
   Flatten[{zt21 /. coefv21, zt22 /. coefv22}]};

p1 = Plot[zz[[1, 1]], {t, 0, 2 nP}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
p2 = Plot[Zt[[1, 1]], {y, 0, 1}];
p3 = Plot[q2[[1, 1]], {y, 1, 2}];
Show[p1, p2, p3, 
 DiscretePlot[Zt[[1, 1]], {y, 0, nP, nP/int}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, Joined -> False, Filling -> None, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}], 
 DiscretePlot[q2[[1, 1]], {y, 1, 2 nP, nP/int}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, Joined -> False, Filling -> None, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}]]
```

Comment: Please post your code, so that readers can reproduce your computation.

Comment: What would be wrong with `Interpolation`?

Comment: @Verbeia thats what I am thinking.How could anything go wrong with interpolation

Comment: It's not what you're thinking; otherwise you'd know that `Interpolation[]` is a built-in function.

Comment: @J.M.isback. That one looks like a Maxwell Smart line

Comment: @ J.M. is back I am doing interpolation to find out the equation of a curve.I can not use interpolation function.And since it is a sinusoidal I have assumed a function which has sine and cosine.Using the data points I created Ax=b type equation so to solve this I am using Linearsolve

Comment: Considering how noisy your data is, interpolation does not seem appropriate. Another thing: you do realize you can use FFT to fit a trigonometric series to your data, no?

Comment: @J.M.isback the data (plotted in red) does not appear to be noisy. That said, this question requires way too much work for my taste (so I'm unlikely to pursue it as it stands). If the data points were put in a .txt file or similar that might be fine. A smaller example would be better still. As a guess, there may be an ill conditioned matrix lurking. The set up with trig polys seems appropriate, but as I said, it is just more work than I want to put in to track down what goes on in the matrix algebra.

Comment: @Daniel, shoot, I mixed up the red and black ones. There indeed is always the possibility of ill-conditioning, which made me think that a Fourier approach just might give slightly better results than piggishly insisting on the linear algebraic route. Well, just my gut feel anyway… :)

Comment: @ Daniel @J.M. Back  I have the discrete fourier transform of the signal but i need the expression for curve thats why I am trying to do interpolation.Is there any other way? I am not able to understand why LinearSolve give me values of coefficients if it does not satisfy the condition(passes through the data points)

Comment: ...so, you're not aware that you can use FFT to compute coefficients and do least-squares fits, I take it?

Comment: DFT gives us the approximate idea regarding the frequencies that are present in the signal.I know the frequencies that must be present in the signal.The only thing that I need is the coefficients. Suppose DFT shows peak at freq 26.1415 but the range of frequencies that I know 26.1415 does not exist but I have three or four frequencies near to this value like 25.9821,26.1327,26.5778,26.771.So now the problem is I need the coefficients of these frequencies.

Comment: @ J M back can you help me in  this?